# Fuzzy screen on startup

Tags: display

I recently started getting a fuzzy screen on start up when booting into Fedora. The best way to describe it is to say the screen looks like it has a H-Scroll problem - fuzzy horizontal lines. The mouse pointer is stable however. My current work around is to log out and back in, then I get a nice stable login screen (difficult to do since you are clicking on menu items you cannot see properly). I´m looking for a permanent fix.

[image: Fuzzy login screen - Fedora]
Fuzzy login screen - Fedora

[image: Clear mouse on fuzzy screen - Fedora]
Clear mouse on fuzzy screen - Fedora

Comment: On Solaris on a Sparc tablet? Or on a plasma screen attached to a raspberry Pi?

Comment: Sorry, it's Fedora. I have added this to the question above

Comment: Can you take a screenshot or take a pic with the phone?

Comment: Have you looked for errors in your Xorg.log?

Comment: How do I do that (ie. where is it kept)? What am I looking for?

Comment: Which GPU do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this exact issue on my machine where I am running both Fedora 20 x64 and Windows 8.1. Sometime in the summer I changed the GPU (Gigabyte GeForce GTX 750 Ti) to support two monitors both using the HDMI interface. Today I needed to switch onto Fedora  and was surprised by the same fuzzy (corrupted) screen on both monitors (LG 22M45).

I did the following (below I list two links where I found the procedure):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> at the fuzzy screen in order to bring up a terminal which was displayed correctly.
2. Then I logged on and performed:

   ```
   sudo yum update
   ```

   Afterwards I did a reboot.
3. Installed the nvidia drivers (the author of the solution recommends akmod instead of `kmod`):

   ```
   sudo yum install kmod-nvidia xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-libs
   ```
4. Finally, I removed Nouveau from `initramfs` by performing:

   ```
   mv /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r)-nouveau.img
   ```

   and, also:

   ```
   dracut /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)
   ```

Then, I did a reboot and the next time the Fedora logon screen appeared correctly.

Here is the original [procedure](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/10603/f18-how-to-install-nvidia-drivers/). The same instructions, but more concise, are also [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=204752).